# Can I use an EntityManager to generate a .sql file instead of writing to a database?

Tags: java, sql, entitymanager

I'm using an EntityManager to write a larger number of new entries to a db. Now a db admin asked me if I could give him a .sql file with all the changes instead of directly accessing the db. Is that possible without creating all the sql statements by hand?

Comment: Why don't you give him a DB dump?

Comment: Because he wants only the changes, not the whole contents, @PankajSharma

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a build-in function that allows for redirecting sql statements to a file instead of sending it to the database. You could use a database logging and interception framework like P6Spy instead and log the actual sql statements using slf4j or similar to a file using a file appender. Just rollback the transaction that originally was in charge to do the actual database work, so that finally the data is not inserted twice.

Maybe this is not the best solution but with the information given, it might be a good one.

Comment: I'll look into this, but I'd still rather not have to write to an actual database just to log what I wrote...

Answer (score 0):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

For OpenJPA/EclipseLink/Hibernate, You can enable SQL Trace to view the sql statements being executed. Or you can use one of JPA monitoring tools.

FYI: Enable SQL Trace for OpenJPA (persistence.xml):

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=false, PrettyPrintLineLength=120, PrintParameters=True"/>
```